# How to configure Tridion core service on Tridion server?

Tags: wcf, configuration, wcf-binding, tridion

When I access Tridion Core Service URL at: `http://tridion_ip/webservices/CoreService2011.svc` I get a Runtime error. I am accessing the URL directly from the CMS server.

> Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the
>   endpoint

When I look in IIS, I can see that the /webservices/ directory shows the following Core Service files:

- CoreService.svc
- CoreService2011.svc
- Web.config

Should I see a web service page at that address? or is this expected beavior?

**EDIT:** Out security element reads as follows:

```
<wsHttpBinding>
 <binding name="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" transactionFlow="true" maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
  <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" maxArrayLength="10485760" />

     <!--
      <security mode="Message">
    <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
  </security>
     -->

  <!-- For LDAP authentication of message credentials, use the following settings: -->
  <security mode="TransportWithMessageCredential">
    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
  </security>

</binding>
```

Comment: What runtime error are you exactly receiving?

Comment: Have you tried this http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithConfigFile or this http://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/GetCoreServiceClientWithoutConfigFile ?

Comment: tridion shows a generic runtime error: Server Error in '/webservices' Application.

Runtime Error

Description: An application error occurred on the server. The current custom error settings for this application prevent the details of the application error from being viewed remotely (for security reasons). It could, however, be viewed by browsers running on the local server machine.

Comment: basically the server has issue to connect to, need some configuration, not client side...

Comment: Lucas, it could be client side too. If the server would only allow HTTPS connections, your client would need a HTTPS binding too. If you're on the same machine, you could try connecting with NetTcp first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check your webservice in IIS. This should be application and check your web.config where your service is installed.

may be you are facing multipile site hosting issue

put this line in webconfig, if it's already exists then replace with old line

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" 
                           multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true"/>
```

Comment: Thanks - We now see this error: Could not find a base address that matches scheme https for the endpoint with binding WSHttpBinding. Registered base address schemes are [http]. Any further ideas?

Comment: Clear answer, could we interest you in committing to the [Area 51 Tridion specific proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/38335/tridion?referrer=gPujQMxthNCNn9xqeeO2NA2). Sign up with the same SO account if you have a moment.

Answer (score 4):

Could you please post security part of your server config? The error you posted usually refers to mismatch between `security mode` and other security settings. Here's how default settings look like:

```xml
  <wsHttpBinding>
    <binding name="CoreService_wsHttpBinding" 
             transactionFlow="true" 
             maxReceivedMessageSize="10485760">
      <readerQuotas maxStringContentLength="10485760" 
                    maxArrayLength="10485760" />
      <security mode="Message">
        <message clientCredentialType="Windows" />
      </security>
    </binding>
  </wsHttpBinding>
```

Having `TransportWithMessageCredential` or `Transport` as `security mode` implies using `HTTPS` and will throw you exception like you have if access through HTTP

**UPDATE** That's indeed what I said. You have TransportWithMessageCredential that assumes you have HTTPs. If you plan to use HTTPs you should disable HTTP on your website but keep in mind that it will also require quite some configuration to make client work with HTTPs. You can always use Message security mode with HTTP. The part you have uncommented is only for LDAP with message security. You can perfectly use LDAP with transport security and use HTTP then.

Comment: thanks everyone, i am trying to connect to this coreservice i got error: There was no endpoint listening at http://tridion/webservices/CoreService2011.svc/basicHttp that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.

Comment: @Lucas Is url and port correct? Can you verify that you can access http://tridion/webservices/CoreService2011.svc through the browser? I hope you have full domain name instead of tridion? If it doesn't help - please ask another question with all details in it